# flask-migrate: can't upgrade database becase "table does not exist"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I am working on a flask application using sqlalchemy with a postgres database. I am migrating my databsed with flask-migrate.
I had to change the name of one of my tables in the database and when trying to migrate (flask-migrate) I got an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.InternalError) cannot drop table category_announcement_date because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint announcement_dates_id_fkey on table announcement_dates depends on table category_announcement_date
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
[SQL: '\nDROP TABLE category_announcement_date']
```

I did not know how to tell flask-migrate about this issue so I came up with the great idea to do it manually so I went to psql and dropped the table together with the CASCADE command as suggested by the error message. That all worked fine but now I can't finish the migration? When running upgrade I get

```
python manage.py db upgrade
...
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) table "category_announcement_date" does not exist
```

which is probably because I just dropped the table manually?
Does anybody know how I can get out of this mess?
thanks carl

Answer (score 1):

ok I noticed deleting the version files and repeating the migrate does the trick
cheers
fl